# libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)

Tags: drivers, video, qt, gpu, gstreamer

I' trying to write a QT application and I'm getting the following error:

```
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
```

this error appeared after I corrected the following error:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

by installing `libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

I tried every possible thing I found to correct the first error. I found that `export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965` could work, but with it, I have the following errors:

```
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
```

It's important to mention that I'm ruinning this program inside an Ubuntu VM, so the driver video might be other one (I don't know, I don't understand about these things)

Comment: I am also getting this issue in 2023, and I think it's because we've installed the Nvidia drivers wrong. Did you ever have a follow-up on this?